# Positionning li item with grid

Tags: css, css-grid

I can't figure out why my li elements are not well positioned in the rows.
I tried a lot of different things, at first I was using nth-childs but I thought it was a problem (even if in my inspector I selected them well), so I switched to IDs to do my tests.
I checked if in my body or something else can block but no

```css
#section2 {
  width: 50%;
}

#sec2grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 30% 70%;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(6, 17%);
}

#section2 ul {
  list-style: none;
}

#section2 li {
  margin-top: 30px;
  font-size: var(--text);
  font-weight: bold;
}

#sec2grid img:nth-child(1) {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-row-start: 1;
}

#sec2grid img:nth-child(2) {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-row-start: 2;
}

#sec2grid img:nth-child(3) {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-row-start: 3;
}

#sec2grid img:nth-child(4) {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-row-start: 4;
}

#sec2grid img:nth-child(5) {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-row-start: 5;
}

#sec2grid img:nth-child(6) {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-row-start: 6;
}

#sec2li1 {
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-row: 1 / 1;
}

#sec2li2 {
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-row: 2 / 2;
}

#sec2li3 {
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-row: 3 / 3;
}

#sec2li4 {
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-row: 4 / 4;
}

#sec2li5 {
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-row: 5 / 5;
}

#sec2li6 {
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-row: 6 / 6;
}
```

```html
<section id="section2">
  <h2>Comment passer<br>une commande ?</h2>
  <div class="separator"></div>
  <div id="sec2grid">
    <img src="style/img/1.svg">
    <img src="style/img/2.svg">
    <img src="style/img/3.svg">
    <img src="style/img/4.svg">
    <img src="style/img/5.svg">
    <img src="style/img/6.svg">
    <ul>
      <li id="sec2li1"><span class="colorGreen">Contactez </span>notre équipe, présentez lui votre besoin.</li>
      <li id="sec2li2">Un interlocuteur dédié étudie votre demande, vous propose une <span class="colorGreen">sélection de produits adaptés</span>et source le matériel auprès de nbotre réseau de partenaires certifiés.</li>
      <li id="sec2li3">Vous choisissez votre garantie : <span class="colorGreen">12 mois ou 24 mois</span></li>
      <li id="sec2li4">Nous vous soumetton un devis, <span class="colorGreen">vous validez votre commande</span></li>
      <li id="sec2li5">En 5 jours ouvrables en moyenne <span class="colorGreen">votre commande vous est espédiée.</span></li>
      <li id="sec2li6">Un <span class="colorGreen">SAV assuré</span>par l'équipe.</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was to not pu height on my "li".
This fix th issues

```
#section2 li{
margin-top: 30px;
font-size: var(--text);
font-weight: bold;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```